# Console.log in ReactJS keeps running

Tags: reactjs

I'm importing a child component and rendering it in my `app.js` file. The component has a `console.log` for debugging but it keeps running the log, seemingly without end. Worried something might be wrong, new to ReactJS and wondering if this is a common issue and how to resolve it.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import axios from 'axios'

import Header from './components/header';
import Page from './components/page';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: 'John Doe',
            nav: {},
            currentPage: "",
            pageContent: "",
            pageTitle: "",
            pageTemplate: "",
            pageId: 0,
            pageCustomMeta: {},
            archiveData: []
        }

    }

    getMainMenu(){
        axios.get('http://admin.sitedata.co/menus/5')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({nav:response.data});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    isHome(){
        //console.log(document.location.pathname);
        if(document.location.pathname === "/") {
            document.body.classList.add('home');
        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove('home');
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        /*
        *   get current page content
        *   get the main menu
        *   allow pageChange function to be ran
        *   allow isHome to be ran
        */

        var slug = "";

        if(document.location.pathname === "/") {
            slug = "home";
        } else {
            slug = document.location.pathname.substr(1);
        }

        this.getPageData(slug);
        this.getMainMenu();
        this.pageChange = this.pageChange.bind(this);
        this.isHome = this.isHome.bind(this);
        this.triggerMenu = this.triggerMenu.bind(this);
        this.triggerHire = this.triggerHire.bind(this);
        this.navigate = this.navigate.bind(this);
        this.setArchiveData = this.setArchiveData.bind(this);
        this.resetArchiveData = this.resetArchiveData.bind(this);
        this.madeChange = this.madeChange.bind(this);
        //document.getElementById('loadingOverlay').classList.add('remove');
    }

    getPageData(slug){
        console.log(this.state);
        axios.get('http://admin.sitedata.co/pages?slug='+slug)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);

            this.setState({
                pageContent:response.data[0].content.rendered,
                currentPage:slug,
                pageTitle:response.data[0].title.rendered,
                pageTemplate:response.data[0].template,
                pageId:response.data[0].id,
                pageCustomMeta:response.data[0].post_meta,
                archiveData:[]
            },function(){
                console.log(this.state);
                /*
                *   set the page title
                *   check if the page is at home
                *   get page custom meta
                */
                document.title = this.state.pageTitle;
                this.isHome();
            });

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    pageChange(e){
        var slug = e.target.getAttribute('data-link');
        var classes = e.target.classList.contains('trigger-hire');

        if(classes){
            this.triggerHire();
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            this.getPageData(slug);
        }       
    }

    setArchiveData(archives) {
        this.setState({archiveData:archives});
    }

    resetArchiveData() {

    }

    navigate (event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        console.log(event.target.tagName);

        if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
            this.props.router.push(event.target.getAttribute('href'));
            console.log('boom');
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    triggerMenu(e){
        var menuOverlay = document.getElementById('menuOverlay');

        if(menuOverlay.classList.contains('active')){
            menuOverlay.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
            menuOverlay.classList.add('active');
        }
    }

    triggerHire(e){
        var hireOverlay = document.getElementById('hireOverlay');

        if(hireOverlay.classList.contains('active')){
            hireOverlay.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
            hireOverlay.classList.add('active');
        }

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    madeChange(){
        alert('changed');
    }

  render() {
    return (

            <div className="App">
            <Header nav={this.state.nav} pageChange={this.pageChange} triggerMenu={this.triggerMenu} triggerHire={this.triggerHire}/>
            <Page madeChange={this.madeChange}
                currentPage={this.state.currentPage} 
                nav={this.state.nav} 
                pageChange={this.pageChange} 
                isHome={this.isHome} 
                pageContent={this.state.pageContent} 
                pageTitle={this.state.pageTitle} 
                pageTemplate={this.state.pageTemplate} 
                pageId={this.state.pageId} 
                pageCustomMeta={this.state.pageCustomMeta} 
                archiveData={this.state.archiveData} 
                triggerHire={this.triggerHire} 
                navigate={this.navigate}  
                setArchiveData={this.setArchiveData} 
            />
            </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Page.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import axios from 'axios'

class Page extends Component {

  render() {

    if(this.props.currentPage){
        var currentPage = this.props.currentPage;
        var pageChange = this.props.pageChange;
        var customMeta = this.props.pageCustomMeta;
        var pageTempalate = this.props.pageTemplate.substr(0,this.props.pageTemplate.length-4);
        var pageTitle = this.props.pageTitle;
        var newTitle = <h1><span><i>{pageTitle}</i></span></h1>;
        var isArchive = "";
        var archiveName = "";

        var firstSpace = pageTitle.indexOf(' ');
        if(firstSpace > -1){
            var firstWord = pageTitle.substr(0, firstSpace);
            var titleLast = pageTitle.substr(firstSpace);
            newTitle = <h1><span><i>{firstWord}</i>{titleLast}</span></h1>
        }

        if(currentPage === "home"){
            if(this.props.nav.items){
                  var navData = this.props.nav;

                  var navHomeItems = navData.items.map(function(navItem){

                     return <li key={navItem.id}><Link to={'/'+navItem.object_slug} className={navItem.classes} onClick={pageChange} data-link={navItem.object_slug}>{navItem.title}</Link></li>;

                  });
              }
        } 

        document.title = this.props.pageTitle;

        var isArchive = customMeta.isArchive;
        var archiveName = customMeta.archiveName
        var worksArchive = "";

        if(customMeta.isArchive && customMeta.isArchive == "true"){

            if(customMeta.archiveName) {

                axios.get('http://admin.sitedata.co/'+customMeta.archiveName)
                .then((response) => {
                    var archivePages = response.data;

                    console.log(archivePages);

                    if(archiveName == "works"){

                        worksArchive = archivePages.map(function(work){

                        //console.log(worksArchive);

                        return <Link key={work.id} className="work-item" to="/" ><img src={work.post_meta.targetimg} /></Link>;

                        });

                        this.props.setArchiveData(worksArchive);

                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }

        if(customMeta.pageColor){
            document.body.classList.add(customMeta.pageColor);
        }

        if(customMeta.bgimg){
            document.body.setAttribute('style', "background-image:url('"+customMeta.bgimg+"');");
        }
    }
    return (
      <Router onEnter={this.props.madeChange}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className={(pageTempalate !== "") ? pageTempalate : ''}>
                {newTitle}
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this.props.pageContent}}></div>
                {this.props.archiveData}
            </div>
          </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: We need to see the code for the component to know. If the `console.log` line is in the render method, it probably means you're re-rendering the component unnecessarily which is inefficient.

Comment: @gunn added the code from both...

Comment: Not addressing the issue, but you really should switch your variable declarations to `const` if you are not going to reassign a value to them, or `let` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

**2024 update**

If you get this its probably because you didnt add dependency to your useEffect.
So, Instead of `useEffect(()=>{})` do `useEffect(()=>{},[])` or anything you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

Distilling your code down to the essential, it looks like this:

```
class Page extends Component {
  render() {
    axios.get(url).then(response=> {
      this.setState({archiveData: response.data})
    })

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.archiveData}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

*(You are doing it differently with a callback that causes the parents to send new props, but the effect is the same).*

You should be able to see problem now: the render method causes a delayed change to state (or props) which in react triggers a new render. So you now have an infinite loop, just delayed by the time taken for an ajax request.

To fix this, you need to remove the ajax request from the render method. In your case, it should probably be in the parent `App` component.